# ngrx store Reducers are subscribing multiple times?

Tags: angular

we have taken Effects and reducers. while subscribing like ,it will subscribe multiple times.

My Reducer is:

```
export const OccText: ActionReducer<AsmntCommonState> =
  (state = defaultCommonText, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "OCC_TEXT_EFFECT": {
        state = { commonText: action.payload }
        // console.log('OCC_TEXT_EFFECT:--' + JSON.stringify(state));

        return state;
      };
      default: {
                   return state;
      }
    }
  }



 store.select("OccText")..subscribe((v) => {
                this.occTxtVal = v;
    }
```

My reducer is subscribing multiple times.. so please give me solution .

Comment: reducer subscribing multiple times? please explain

Comment: Lets say there are multiple reducers in the app. Here OccText is just one reducer. So here if I am dispatching "OCC_TEXT_EFFECT" of OccText then other reducer's **'default'** case in switch case is getting executed.